# What happened to Stannis's preserved fetuses

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

So as of *Game of Thrones* season 7 Daenerys is in Dragonstone now and there hasn't been a mention of Stannis's preserved fetuses as of yet that I can tell.

Were they taken north or are they just forgotten?

There might be something I missed.

Comment: They weren't Stannis', they belonged to Selyse Baratheon. Presumably she took them with her when she left Dragonstone.

Comment: @Paulie_D Do we ever see them north? Also if we're splitting hairs women don't really own anything unless they are the last ones alive in their family as it belongs to the man in Game of Thrones thus the Dorn plot and Daenerys shaky claim to the throne and entire progressive theme. Also Cersei can't forget her though that might be the negative perspective

Comment: She kept them in her chambers...they were important to *her*..not him. I doubt if we ever saw them again after S3.

Comment: I've vtc'd this question as primarily opinion-based.  So far there's no in-show explanation, so any answers will be speculation.

Comment: @DForck42 then that is the answer to the question that we don't know. Wasn't sure if we/I missed something. Make it an answer showcasing they have not been brought up again and I'll accept it

Comment: Or it could always be put on hold until the end of the series where undoubtedly we will have undead fetuses warring on their claim to the iron throne

Comment: Obviously they were [consumed and eaten for their extraordinary rejuvenative properties](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNJi0CzfodI)

Comment: I think we're having a disagreement over what's opinion and what's not. If there is no data, that's not an opinion, it's a lack of information. If we don't have information, the answer is "This hasn't been explained in the show, so we can not answer the question without theorizing".

Comment: @Catija "We don't know it has not been covered as of insert date here" is valid and not opinion it could be put on-hold until the end of the series and if the series ends with it not coming up then "We don't know" is the answer

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing... but we don't put questions on hold just because we don't have answers for them... we can just leave them open until the show is over or someone can post an answer that says "No one knows, it's not covered in the show and the writers haven't said anything about it"... and if we are told (which I doubt will happen) someone can write a new answer that explains it.

Comment: @Catija agreed seems we are saying the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL; DR:** We don't currently know.

In Season 4, after Joffrey's death, Stannis gathers his forces and heads north toward the wall.  We never see these fetuses being toted along, so we can only assume they were either left at Dragon Stone or taken with them.  After the scenes we've seen from Dragon Stone in Season 7, it looks like they took everything they could with them, save unimportant things.  Stannis is, mostly, not an idiot and would know that taking them would be pointless in the fight.

Chances are that the fetuses were left at Dragon Stone, but they aren't an important part of the story at this point so they haven't been included since Danny took over.

Comment: I disagree the fetuses have kings blood, could have saved his daughters life, but thanks for the answer.